# How to display publisher name along with the book name,as the code i am using now shows only book names.//using html using django?

Tags: html, python-2.7, django-models

To display name of the books,code implemented is : 
search_results.html :

```
    {% if books %}           
        <p>Found {{ books|length }} book{{ books|pluralize }}.</p>
        <ul>               
            {% for book in books %}               
            <li>{{ book.title }}</li>           
            {% endfor %}              
        </ul> 
    {% else %}
```

Now my question is how to show publisher name of same book along with the book name?

modelss.py:

```
class publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
{% for book in books %}               
    <li>{{ book.title }} - {{ book.publisher.name }}</li>           
{% endfor %}
```

I also suggest you to use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for this situations because if you have **N** books this will result to **N** extra database queries.

I don't know how your **view** function looks like but if you want to list all the books along with the publisher informations then your ORM query in your **view** function should look like this:

`books = book.objects.select_related("publisher")`.

P.S.

Your class names should follow **InitialCaps**/**CapWords** pattern as well. In your situation you should have `class Publisher` instead of `class publisher` and `class Book` instead of `class book`.